# Salesforce Webservice Error

Tags: web-services, soap, salesforce, apex-code

I am receiving the following error from a class that invokes a webservice.

```
"You have uncommitte​d work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out"
```

Here is the class that is calling the webservice:

```
global class myWS   
{   

   WebService static string invokeExternalWs(string childValue, string parentValue)   
    {   
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();   
        req.setEndpoint('https://externalURL/Services');   
        req.setMethod('POST');   
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');   
        req.setHeader('SOAPAction', 'http://externalService/externalMethod');  
        string b = '--soap request goes here--';   
        req.setBody(b);   
        Http http = new Http();   
        try {   
          //Execute web service call here 
          String xObjectID ='';   
          HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
          Dom.Document doc = res.getBodyDocument();
          String soapNS = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'; 
          Dom.XmlNode root = doc.getRootElement();
          for(dom.XmlNode node1 : root.getChildElements()) {
               for(dom.XmlNode node2 : node1.getChildElements()) {
                   for(dom.XmlNode node3 : node2.getChildElements()) {
                      for(dom.XmlNode node4 : node3.getChildElements()) {
                          xObjectID = node4.getText();
                       }
                   }
               }
             }

         return xObjectID;
       } catch(System.CalloutException e){   
          return 'ERROR:' + e;   
     }          
}   
}
```

UPDATE: Here is my class that is executing myWS

```
public void applyURLString(ID ArgBuildID) {

    Builder__c current_build = [SELECT id, name, LLURL__c, column1, column2, Opportunity__c
                FROM Builder__c
                WHERE id = :ArgBuildID];

        if(current_build.LLURL__c == null || current_build.LLURL__c.trim().length() == 0)
            {

                String tmpFolderName = current_build.column1 + ' - ' + current_build.column2;

                String LLWSResultPattern = '[0-9]{2,}';

                String myWSXMLResult = myWS.invokeExternalWs(tmpFolderName,'test');

                Boolean LLWSPatternMatched = pattern.matches(LLWSResultPattern,myWSXMLResult);
                if(LLWSPatternMatched)
                {
                    Opportunity oppt = [SELECT Id,Name 
                                        FROM Opportunity 
                                        WHERE Id = :current_build.Opportunity__c
                                        LIMIT 1];   
                    oppt.LLURL__c = 'https://someService/' + myWSXMLResult;
                    update oppt;
                } 
            } 
    }
```

UPDATE #2 - Here is where applyURLString() is executed. This is the only place that DML is executed prior to my HTTP request. Yet I need the ID of the new Builder record.

```
Builder__c insertBuild = new Builder__c();      
insertBuild.Opportunity__c = opportunityId;
insertBuild.Product_Group__c = selectedBuild.Product_Group__c;
insertBuild.Manual_Build_Product__c = selectedBuild.Manual_Build_Product__c;

insert insertBuild;

applyURLString(insertBuild.Id);
```

Any ideas why this error would occur?

Comment: We would need to see the class/trigger that is calling this class - you will receive this message if you are making the callout after updating the database.

Comment: Ok I added the execution code above.

Comment: Updated again (#2) with code I assume is causing the issue.

Comment: You have a DML statement (insert insertBuild;) just prior to making the call to applyURLString. Like I said before, you'll get this message if you try to make a callout after making an update to the database in the same transaction. I might suggest making the applyURLString method a future callout to get around this.

Comment: @future did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@JCD's suggestion to use an @future annotation solved my problem. Thanks again!